# database engine tuning wizard "apply recommendations" is disabled

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I just forced the database engine tuning wizard in ssms 2008 to analyze a 5mb trace.

I got a list of recommendations returned to me, in terms of indexes to implement; however, I am unable to apply the recommendations because it is greyed out:

[image]

Does anyone know whether this is a bug? How would I manually implement the changes?

Thank you so much for your guidance.

Comment: How did you get `Start Analysis` to work, if it's also greyed out?

Comment: yes i did! it started and gave me a bunch fo recommendations

Comment: estimated improvement says "0%" however i think it will definitely help what it suggested

Comment: Maybe that's why it's not offering to apply the recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply click the right most column that looks like hyperlink and it will open a popup window which will have the recommended index or statistic in query form. You can click Copy to Clipboard from the popup window. Now paste it in to your SSMS New Query window and execute it.

The only reason I think 'Apply Recommendations' menu item is disabled is either you don't have  enough permissions to make those changes or the session has timed out.

Hope this helps!